# sub string losing string input

Tags: c++, string, substring

very odd because I never had this issue before.

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::string useInput = useInput.substr(0, 15);
```

trying to figure out what's wrong with my program & I've figured out that for whatever reason when my string is passing the input into the sub string, it's been erasing the data from the string. When I use

```
std::cout << input;
```

It displays what I typed without issue or error, but when I try using

```
std::cout << useInput;
```

It displays nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may mean to have:
    `std::string useInput = input.substr(0,15);`

instead of 
    `std::string useInput = useInput.substr(0, 15);`

Comment: omg... i've been trying to figure out this for over 3 hours now... how did I miss that. Thank you so much, you have put my frustration at ease.

Comment: No problem friend! Hope you have a great rest of your programming day!

Comment: You as well, because of you I surely will :D